# How do I manipulate a text file with regex?

Tags: regex, text-files

I exported all my tweets to a text file, but I want to do some manipulation on it to format it differently. It seems to me that the easiest way to do this would be with regular expressions, but I don't have much experience with them.

Current format:

```
User: Jack
Text: Hello world!
Created At: July 06 22:55:33 2012

---

User: Jill
...
```

Format I would like to get it to:

```
Hello World!

July 06, 2012 at 10:55PM via [Jack](http://twitter.com/Jack)

---

...
```

Can anyone help me figure out what the regex would be? The trickiest part is changing the timestamp form 24h to 12h. I also want to reverse the order (most recent at the bottom instead of at the top), but I'm not sure how easy that would be to do.

Comment: You could parse it with regular expressions if you'd like, but it's such a simple format I don't think you'd need them. You'll need something else to do the 24h to 12h transformation. What language are you using?

Comment: The 24h to 12h could also be done mostly in regex, if the programming language supports a function as a `Replace` argument. (eg Javascript, .NET)

Comment: I'm using find and replace in my text editor to delete a bunch of metadata and thought I could use regular expressions to finish off the last bit of manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reordering, but leaving the time as 24h:

Search: `User: (.+)\nText: (.+)\nCreated At: (\w+ \d+) (\d+:\d+:\d+) (\d+)\n`

Replace: `\2\n\n\3, \5 at \4 via [\1](http://twitter.com/\1)\n`

The replacement pattern may need `$1` instead of `\1`, etc, depending on the regex flavour.

Group 1 is username

Group 2 is text

Group 3 is month and day of month

Group 4 is time of day

Group 5 is year

Converting 24h to 12h using simple regex is possible, but best done with the help of a programming language.